# Defining symbols to their quoted counterparts in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to define symbols to themselves in quote. I can do this define by define like so:

```
#lang racket
(define a 'a)
(define b 'b)
```

But if I want to do this for a lot of values how would I go about it? I know there is `define-values` but how can I extract the variable names from a list?

```
(define vs '(a b))
(define-values ??? (apply values vs))
```

---

EDIT: [soegaard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37362650/738768) works well. As a follow-up, how would you do the same for `define-syntax-rule` (or an equivalent using other macro definition functions) i.e. have `a` be replaced by `'a` on a syntax level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macro below will turn

```
(define-symbols a b c)
```

into

```
(begin
  (define a 'a)
  (define b 'b)
  (define c 'c))
```

The macro:

```
#lang racket
(require (for-syntax syntax/parse))

(define-syntax (define-symbols stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    [(_define-symbols id:id ...)
     (syntax/loc stx
       (begin
         (define id 'id)
         ...))]
    [_ (raise-syntax-error 'define-symbols
                           "Expected (define-symbols <identifier> ...)"
                           stx)]))

(define-symbols a b c)
(list a b c a b c)
```

EDIT

Here is a syntax-rules version:

```
(define-syntax define-symbols
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_define-symbols id ...)
     (begin
       (define id 'id)
       ...)]))
```

Note however that this version does not check that the id's are identifiers.

For example `(define-symbols 3)` will lead to a misleading error message.

Comment: The syntax error case in the `syntax-rules` version is unreachable, and even if it were reachable, it would result in `. stx: unbound identifier in module in: stx`, and even if that weren't true, it would raise an error at run-time, not compile-time. So it's probably better to leave it out of the `syntax-rules` version?

Comment: I vaguely remember that there exists a syntax-rules twist that makes it possible to check that something is an identifier, but it was pretty obscure.

Comment: For `syntax-case` there is if you write exactly two "body" expressions, is that what you were thinking of?

Comment: After some digging:  http://okmij.org/ftp/Scheme/macros.html#macro-symbol-p   Oleg and Al Petrofsky were (are) known for making syntax-rules do things that seem impossible. More here: http://okmij.org/ftp/Scheme/macro-symbol-p.txt

Comment: Doesn't that fail for literal boxes, hash tables, strings, byte-strings, regexps, and prefab structs? Oh wait... no it doesn't.